# large file transfer write-progress not updating in real-time

Tags: windows-7, powershell-3.0

I am attempting to write progress on a large file copy in powershell.  I have the progress bar working quite well with small file copies, but when I transfer over a gig of data the progress bar does not update in real time.  I can check the folder I am copying to and see that everything is transferring as it should, however, my progress bar just sits on the same file and the bar itself doesn't seem to move at all.  I am using CredSSP to invoke the command on a server at our data center, so I'm not sure if that is making a difference in the write-progress cmdlet or not.  Here is an excerpt of my script:

```
$credential = Get-Credential -Credential domain\user
$session = New-PSSession  -ComputerName server.domain.edu -Credential $credential -authentication CredSSP

Invoke-Command -session $session -ScriptBlock {

$path = "\\domain\shares\dfsdatacenter" + "-DC" + "\HomeDir\ttest1"
$dest = "\\server\Archive$\Terminated"
$counter = 0
$files = gci $path -recurse  | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer; } 


             Foreach($file in $files)
             {
              Copy-Item $path $dest -recurse -force 
              Write-Progress -Activity "Backing Up Terminated User HomeDir:" -status $file.FullName -PercentComplete ($counter / $files.count*100) 
              $counter++           
             }

        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer!

Comment: Do you test your small files transfer using the CredSSP?

Comment: No, but regardless of whether I was using credssp to run it on a remote server or whether I ran it from my own machine, I would have this problem.  When I run it directly from the server it does not seem to update the progress in real time either.  If there is a better way to transfer files and get progress on it, I'd sure like to know it. For a small transfer, this works great.